# XL_CHART_TYPE.DOUGHNUT set hole size

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm trying to make doughnut chart with `python-pptx`. I need to set custom hole size, and it should be holeSize attribute, but i can't find it.

Can anybody help me?

```
chart = ph.insert_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.DOUGHNUT, chart_data).chart
s = chart.series[0]
s.format.element.set('holeSize', '70')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work, at least if the `c:holeSize` element is already present in the XML (I believe it will be). This can be condensed to probably a couple lines, I'm spelling each step out separately here for clarity on what's happening:

```
chart = ph.insert_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.DOUGHNUT, chart_data).chart
# ---the c:doughnutChart parent of c:holeSize is at the plot level---
doughnut_plot = chart.plots[0]
# ---access the <c:doughnutChart> element---
doughnutChart = doughnut_plot._element
# ---from then on it's all lxml calls---
holeSizes = doughnutChart.xpath('./c:holeSize')
if len(holeSizes) == 0:
    raise ValueError('sorry, no c:holeSize element present')
holeSize = holeSizes[0]
holeSize.set('val', '70')
```

Comment: How can I add a text inside this doughnut hole?